# Setup Git repo as server (origin) and get its url

Tags: git

I want to setup a git repo which will be cloned by others. This server is, say, gitserver.com.

So in my project directory of gitserver.com ~/nodejs/project I did git init, git add and git commit.

Now to clone this on a different machine, I tried the following: -

```
git clone ssh://root@gitserver.com/nodejs/project
git clone ssh://root@gitserver.com/nodejs/project.git
git clone git://root@gitserver.com/nodejs/project
git clone git://root@gitserver.com/nodejs/project.git
```

But I get this error -

> Cloning into 'project'... fatal: '/nodejs/project.git' does not appear
>   to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

So am I missing any step? How do I get the url of the repo created in gitserver.com?

Comment: The remote repository must be created with bare flag (because it don't need the working directory) `git init --bare yourproject.git` More info: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between local and remote git repos. Remote in a sence that it's central repository, origin.

In ~remote/project directory

> git init --bare

Go to your local directory

> git remote add origin ~/remote/project
>
> git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
>
> git push -u origin master